# Change the transport of a git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I created a new repository for one of my project on Gitlab/Github. I created it and started to use it with command line tools with SSH transport protocol. Now I'm using Visual Studio and Visual Studio 2013 doesn't support SSH. When I try to do a push I get this error message

> An error occurred. Detailed message: This transport isn't implemented.
>   Sorry

Can I change something in my local git repository to change from SSH to HTTPS.

I know that I can still use my command line tool and do the push but for my personal knowledge I would like to know if I can easy change the transport protocol or relocate the repository. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command-line, you simply can change the origin url; from an ssh one to an https one (using [`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)):

```
git remote set-url origin https://<yourgitlabsever>/<youraccount>/<yourrepo>
```

That will be picked up by Visual Studio, which will use the new (supported) url.
No need to "relocate" the repo.